# HTTP Error 500.0 - ASP.NET Core IIS hosting failure (in-process)

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I get this error when run my aspcore application in visualstudio2022.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkCrd.png)

I have this folder in bin/debug folder of project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Anwr.png)

and I have this line of code in web.config

```
<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
```

and when I see eventViewer in windows get this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8gYb.png)

Could You help me what should todo to run my project?

Comment: What's the error details found into your `event viewer` logs? could you please share the details?

Answer (score 0):

change **stdoutLogEnabled="false"** ==> **stdoutLogEnabled="true"** and then check for logs in ".\logs\stdout" for detailed error.

Comment: i did it . it show the same error.